# Show my communities in hamburger menu when browsing a unjoined community

Tags: feature-request, bug, mobile-web, top-bar

In the desktop view, when we browse a site which we are not a member of, we are shown a list of sites and the reputation and badges shown on it when we click on the hamburger.

[image: Hamburger menu while browsing a site before joining on desktop]

This doesn't happen on mobile web.

[image: Hamburger menu while browsing a site before joining on mobile web]

Joined communities are not shown on mobile web. They show just like when we are logged out. It is difficult back to communities which we are members of.

So, add a list of joined communities list on mobile web like it is on desktop site.

Comment: Yeah, that's an oversight. We're also working on responsive design that will eventually (as far as I know) take the place of these mobile views, so this sort of divergence shouldn't be much of a thing eventually.

Comment: @AdamLear May I ask what is the expected timeline on the responsive design changes? I thought the responsive design was going to be deployed to MSE around now. I am just a little eager to see the changes.

Comment: @KodosJohnson It's currently enabled for Teams users on Stack Overflow. We're *almost* ready to deploy to MSE as well. The groundwork we need to lay to make things extendable to other site themes turned out to be larger than expected, but we're close. Probably a week or two out, barring any new roadblocks.